# How can I set the password of a user created in a fixture

Tags: meteor

I would like to create a user in my fixture and to be able to sign in as that user. For this reason, I need to somehow set the password of the user (if I try to sign in without a password, I get a 'User has no password set' validation error).

So far I only have:

```
var joeId = Meteor.users.insert({
    username: 'joe'
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_createuser you can do this:

```
Accounts.createUser({
  'username'  : 'John Doe',
  'email'     : 'john@doe.com',
  'password'  : 'abc123' //encrypted automatically 
}, function(err){
  if(typeof err === 'undefined'){
    //account created successfully you might want to send an email to the user using Account.sendEnrollmentEmail()
  }
});
```

Which will login with that user on successful creation.

Answer (score 3):

Meteor complains about "Error: Accounts.createUser with callback not supported on the server yet." as of Meteor 0.6.4 if trying to create user on server side fixtures.

Just add the following after creating Joe:

```
Accounts.setPassword(joeId, 'my great password')
```